# Finding a relation between two functions $f(t)$ and $g(t)$ defined by an integral equation

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, analysis, definite-integrals

Consider the following integral equation
$$
\int_0^r \left( \frac{t^{k+1} f(t)}{\left(r^2-t^2\right)^\frac{1}{2}}
-t^{k-1} 
\left( (2k-1)\left(r^2-t^2\right)^\frac{1}{2} - \frac{t^2}{\left(r^2-t^2\right)^\frac{1}{2}} \right) g(t)  \right) \mathrm{d}t = h_k(r) , 
$$
where the right hand side of this integral equations is given by
$$
h_k(r) = \frac{r^4}{\left(r^2+1\right)^\frac{3}{2}} \, \delta_{k1}\, ,
$$
wherein $\delta$ is the Kronecker delta.
Here, $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

> The goal is to find a relation between the two functions $f(t)$ and $g(t)$.

i tried to use the usual procedure by multiplying both members of the integral equation by $r \,\mathrm{d}r/ \left(s^2-r^2\right)^\frac{1}{2}$ and then integrating wrt. $r$ between $0$ and $s$.
However, this approach does not seem to be helpful.

i was wondering whether someone here could try to be of help and let us know if a relation between $f(t)$ and $g(t)$ could be obtained.
Hints and comments welcome.
Thanks